# Postgres column to have Autoincrement feature based on values on another key column

Tags: postgresql, auto-increment

I have a requirement where i need to design the table in postgres, where one of the column needs to have autoincrement feature. But the autoincrement should be based on the value on another column.
Table

```
Column A   Column B
100           1
101           1
102           1
102           2
102           3
```

column A and Column B are the keys to the table. Now if i insert another row, with Column A equated as 100, then column B needs to auto populate as 2. If i attempt to insert value 102 into column A, then column B needs to populate on its own as 4.
Is there a way i can set an attribute to column B, during table creation?

Thanks
Sadiq

Comment: No. What is the use case here?

Comment: Actual table has 3 columns. Column A and Column C will always be unique. Column A has the reference Id and column C will have a string associated to it. User would have to update the string associated with the id (column A) often. When they do so, new row has to be created in the table with sequence number incremented. I can do the same using max of sequence number for the same id (value present in column A), but wanted to explore if there are any column setting that can accomplish this

Comment: Would it not be easier to just use an `insert_timestamp` field with `DEFAULT now()`?  Then you would have the sequential order of inserts.

Answer (score 0):

@AdrianKlaver is correct. You should use a timestamp and actually record when the version was saved. If you want the version number then you can generate it with the Window row_number function when queried.

```
select column_a 
     , row_number() over (partition by column_a
                              order by column_a,column_a_ver_ts) column_b
  from table_name;
```

Alternative you could use the above query and create a view. See [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=fabc923497e328d80f35a06cb1be5abb)